# Conditionals inside Channel Entries tag to determine whether a second tag is required

Tags: channel-entries, categories, stash, conditionals

### Current Setup

- I have 5 entries in the "internal_ads" channel that rotate on the
  homepage.
- I have set up a category of "urgent" that has 1 entry in it.
- I'm using stash to set a list of adverts, then running through the list in my template to get them to rotate.

### What I want to happen

When an entry is added to the `urgent` category, I want that entry to be the *only* ad to display.

### What I've tried

I currently have the following in my initial template that sets the stash list and works correctly for getting the 5 ads.

```
{stash:embed:layouts:homepage}

{!-- Set data for Internal Adverts --}
     {exp:stash:set_list name="internal_ads" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
          {exp:channel:entries channel="internal_adverts" dynamic="no" orderby="random" limit="1"}
                    {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
                    {stash:advert_title}{title}{/stash:advert_title}
                    {stash:short_description}{short_description}{/stash:short_description}
                    {stash:homepage_image}{homepage_image}{/stash:homepage_image}
         {/exp:channel:entries}
     {/exp:stash:set_list}
```

I have tried the following using conditionals to try checking if there's an entry in the `urgent` category and if there *isn't* then set the list as before. If there is, then only use that entry. It doesn't want to work and I can't really see why.

```
{stash:embed:layouts:homepage}

{!-- Set data for Internal Adverts --}
    {exp:stash:set_list name="internal_ads" parse_tags="yes" parse_depth="2"}
        {exp:channel:entries channel="internal_adverts" dynamic="no" orderby="random" limit="1" category="36"}
            {if no_results}
                {/exp:channel:entries}
                {exp:channel:entries channel="internal_adverts" dynamic="no" orderby="random" limit="1"}
                    {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
                    {stash:advert_title}{title}{/stash:advert_title}
                    {stash:short_description}{short_description}{/stash:short_description}
                    {stash:homepage_image}{homepage_image}{/stash:homepage_image}
                {/exp:channel:entries}
            {if:else}
                {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
                {stash:advert_title}{title}{/stash:advert_title}
                {stash:short_description}{short_description}{/stash:short_description}
                {stash:homepage_image}{homepage_image}{/stash:homepage_image}
            {/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few different approaches to this. In my opinion I don't think this is an appropriate use of categories: rather, I would use a custom PT checkbox-group field called 'options', or alternatively use the 'sticky' functionality. Here's how you could use a PT checkbox group:

```
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="data"
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_conditionals="yes"
    parse_depth="2"
}   
    {exp:channel:entries
         channel="internal_adverts"
         dynamic="no"
         orderby="random"
    }
        {if {options:selected option="urgent"}}
            {exp:stash:set_value name="urgent" value="true"}
        {/if}

        {stash:options}{options}{/stash:options}
        {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
        {stash:advert_title}{title}{/stash:advert_title}
        {stash:short_description}{short_description}{/stash:short_description}
        {stash:homepage_image}{homepage_image}{/stash:homepage_image}

    {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{!-- ==============================
TEST OUTPUT 
=================================== --}

{exp:stash:parse process="end"}

    {if "{exp:stash:urgent}"}
        {exp:stash:get_list name="data" match="#Urgent#" against="options" limit="1"}
            <h3>Skirmish mode! Just show {advert_title}</h3>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
    {if:else}
        <h3>Regular mode, loop through all ads:</h3>
        <ul>
        {exp:stash:get_list name="data"}
            <li>{advert_title}</li>
        {/exp:stash:get_list}
        </ul>
    {/if}

{/exp:stash:parse}
```

There are a few further examples of using these kind of 'switches' in Stash in my level-1 tutorial here: http://www.jamessmith.co.uk/articles/expressionengine-stash-tutorial-level-1#switches

Answer (score 0):

Not that this will fix your issue but you have an extraneous {/exp:channel:entries} tag here:

[image]

Comment: Could be wrong but I think he put that there on purpose, I see what he's trying to do by attempting to close the channel entries tag early and start a new one instead!

Comment: But he doesn't start a new one later to reopen it.

Comment: You're correct here, but you've highlighted the wrong close tag in the image as the one you've referenced makes sense. The one a line from the bottom in your picture is the one that shouldn't be there. However, I realised this within about a minute of posting this question, and alas, it fixes nothing. Thank you though!